# How do I make ABCPdf to automatically write to a new page when text requires more than 1 page?

Tags: dynamic, abcpdf, truncated

I deal with dynamic input text, so the pages should be dynamically created. If page 1 is already full, it should write to a new page, so it means I can have page 2, page 3 and so on depending on the data processed.

Currently, my text is truncated. Only writes Page 1, the rest of data are not written.

My current code below:

```
//add page 1
theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
theDoc.AddImageHtml(html, true, 826, true);

//continue adding page if needed                             
while (theDoc.GetInfo(theID, "Truncated") == "1")
{
   theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
   theDoc.AddImageHtml(html, true, 826, true);
}

//save file
String pdfFilePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pdfFilePath"];
Guid fileName = Guid.NewGuid();
pdfLink = pdfFilePath + fileName.ToString() + ".pdf";
theDoc.Save(pdfLink);
theDoc.Clear();
```

variable html contains all the data(webpage), I'm probably missing something in my while loop. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Found it, Use Chainable and then Flatten()

theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
int theID;
theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");

while (true) {
theDoc.FrameRect(); // add a black border
if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
  break;
theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
}

for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++) {
   theDoc.PageNumber = i;
  theDoc.Flatten();
}
```